# How do I in-line install a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In the last 1.5 weeks, I've been going through a lot of somewhat outdated documentation to try and figure out the "right way" to install a self-hosted self-updating Firefox Extension. I used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages and the `InstallTrigger.install(...)` method to point to a URL. I got it to work a little bit, but it seems so brittle that there has to be a better way.

Is there a new way in `jpm` to do this? Is there a code sample I can look to make this actually work?

Right now I am running into the issue where `"The add-on being downloaded is not the one Mozilla expects"` which I'm pretty sure means the hashes are mismatched. However, I've triple checked the hash of the .xpi file (SHA1) and had it working previously and it just refuses to stay put. Here is my code in TypeScript.

```
element.click((event: JQueryEventObject) =>

    {
        var params = {
            "My Extension": {
                URL: "https://(redacted for privacy)/addon.xpi",
                Hash: "sha1:ef5662925bbf6d32ff5554bb4edb34b44045ada6"
            }
        };  
        InstallTrigger.install(params);
    });
```

That's it. When they click the link, it should install.

Any help here is appreciated. Is InstallTrigger the only way to in line install an extension?

Comment: How do you sign your addons?

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Basilevs - I submitted my extension to the Mozilla store as an unlisted add-on. It is a brand new extension.

@matagus - We support 38+ so I can `jpm` I think. I also use Firefox 41 (now 42).

Comment: It would be nice if you share you .xpi and the algorithm checksum you're using. I've tested you code with my addon using sha1sum and it works like a charm. https://gist.github.com/matagus/003672ba7bf062819a36

Comment: @matagus I don't know what I did but the code starting working correctly. Your gist was very helpful. I think it had something to do with the root of my website being different across environments or possibly my devbox's Firefox being broken